# How to print historical prices for a series of stocks with Python?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am quite new to Python and I am trying to print stock prices for a series of stocks, here is my code:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

tickers = [Share('AAPL'), Share('T')]

print(tickers.get_historical('2016-01-01', '2016-10-31'))
```

As a result, I get the error `'list' object has no attribute 'get_historical'`. I imagine that the mistake is in how I defined "tickers", can anyone help on this?

Comment: I had your answer on the question you just deleted.  If you want the answer, go ahead and undelete it.

Comment: thanks, I solved the other issue

Answer (score 3):

`tickers` is a list, and lists don't have a `get_historical` method. I assume `get_historical` is a method of the Share class, in which case I suggest doing:

`print([t.get_historical('2016-01-01', '2016-10-31') for t in tickers])`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `get_historical` on `tickers` which you defined as a list

```
tickers = [Share('AAPL'), Share('T')]
```

hence the error `'list' object has no attribute 'get_historical'`
Try calling it on a specific share instead:

```
yahoo = Share('APPL')
yahoo.get_historical('2016-01-01', '2016-10-31')
```

as per the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.3.2), or per item in the list.